# Create the clone of a card element with an onClick button

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, react-redux

I am having troubles with my code and can't find a solution to it, basically i'm trying to clone a card element when clicking on a 'plus' button, to 'add a member'.  I am working with `react-redux`. 
I wanna be able to add two other members (no more) with different datas in each of them which is why I have done three, so this is what I got in my store:

```
team :[{
      Firstname: "",
      Age: "",
      Role: "",
      Statut: "",
      Money: "",
      Formation: 0,
      Experience: 0,
      Reseau: 0,
      Rating: 0,
    },
     {
      Firstname1: "",
      Age1: "",
      Role1: "",
      Statut1: "",
      Money1: "",
      Formation1: 0,
      Experience1: 0,
      Reseau1: 0,
      Rating1: 0,
     },
     {
      Firstname2: "",
      Age2: "",
      Role2: "",
      Statut2: "",
      Money2: "",
      Formation2: 0,
      Experience2: 0,
      Reseau2: 0,
      Rating2: 0,
     }
    ]
```

And this is what is in my component (the `<link>`/`<button>` is at the very end of the code):

```
class TeamEditor extends Component{
   render() {  
      return(
        // BACKGROUND CARD //
        <div className="mr-2">
        <Card className= "Editor-card"> 
          <Row>
            <Col md={4}>
              <CardHeader className="card-header-warning card-header-icon">
                  <div className="card-icon card-icon-team">
                    <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '../assets/images/001-trade.svg' } width="40px" className="icon" alt="icon"/> 
                  </div>
                  <h3 className="float-left card-category mt-2"><span className="text-team">Notre équipe</span></h3>
              </CardHeader>
            </Col> 
            <Col  md={8} >
              <NavLink to="/" className="d-flex justify-content-end mt-0">
                <Button className= "mt-3">Enregistrer et quitter</Button>
              </NavLink> 
            </Col>
          </Row> 
          {/* CARD NUMBER ONE */}
            <Card className="InsideCard">
              <CardBody>  
                <Form>
                  <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="examplePrenom">Mon Prénom</Label>
                        <Input type="Prenom" name="Prenom" id="examplePrenom" value={this.props.Firstname} onChange={this.props.setFirstname}/>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={1}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="examplePassword">Mon âge</Label>
                        <Input type="Age" name="Age" id="exampleAge" value={this.props.Age} onChange={this.props.setAge} />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="exampleFonction">Ma fonction</Label>
                        <Input type="Fonction" name="Fonction" id="exampleFonction" value={this.props.Role} onChange={this.props.setRole} />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>  
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label className="labelForm" for="StatutSocial">Mon statut</Label>
                        <Input type="select" name="StatutSocial" id="StatutSocial" value={this.props.Statut} onChange={this.props.setStatut}>
                          <option>Actionnaire</option>
                          <option>Gérant.e ou co Gérant.e</option>
                          <option>Salarié.e</option>
                          <option>Soutien</option>
                        </Input>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="Finance">Mes attentes financière</Label>
                        <Input type="Finance" name="Attente Financiere" id="Finance" value={this.props.Money} onChange={this.props.setMoney}/>    
                      </FormGroup>
                   </Col>
                </Row>
            </Form>
           <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around mt-3" >
              <p className= "Passion">Passion</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Expérience</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Réseau</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Formation</p> 
           </Row>
           <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Passion} onChange={this.props.setPassion} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Experience} onChange={this.props.setExperience} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Reseau} onChange={this.props.setReseau} count={4}  size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} /> 
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Formation} onChange={this.props.setFormation} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
           </Row> 
         </CardBody> 
        </Card> 
        {/* CARD NUMBER TWO */}
        <Card className="InsideCard">
              <CardBody>  
                <Form>
                  <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="examplePrenom">Mon Prénom</Label>
                        <Input type="Prenom" name="Prenom" id="examplePrenom" value={this.props.Firstname1} onChange={this.props.setFirstname1}/>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={1}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="examplePassword">Mon âge</Label>
                        <Input type="Age" name="Age" id="exampleAge" value={this.props.Age1} onChange={this.props.setAge1} />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="exampleFonction">Ma fonction</Label>
                        <Input type="Fonction" name="Fonction" id="exampleFonction" value={this.props.Role1} onChange={this.props.setRole1} />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>  
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label className="labelForm" for="StatutSocial">Mon statut</Label>
                        <Input type="select" name="StatutSocial" id="StatutSocial" value={this.props.Statut1} onChange={this.props.setStatut1}>
                          <option>Actionnaire</option>
                          <option>Gérant.e ou co Gérant.e</option>
                          <option>Salarié.e</option>
                          <option>Soutien</option>
                        </Input>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="Finance">Mes attentes financière</Label>
                        <Input type="Finance" name="Attente Financiere" id="Finance" value={this.props.Money1} onChange={this.props.setMoney1}/>    
                      </FormGroup>
                   </Col>
                </Row>
            </Form>
           <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around mt-3" >
              <p className= "Passion">Passion</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Expérience</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Réseau</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Formation</p> 
           </Row>
           <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Passion1} onChange={this.props.setPassion1} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Experience1} onChange={this.props.setExperience1} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Reseau1} onChange={this.props.setReseau1} count={4}  size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} /> 
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Formation1} onChange={this.props.setFormation1} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
           </Row> 
         </CardBody> 
        </Card> 
        {/* CARD NUMBER THREE */}
        <Card className="InsideCard">
              <CardBody>  
                <Form>
                  <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="examplePrenom">Mon Prénom</Label>
                        <Input type="Prenom" name="Prenom" id="examplePrenom" value={this.props.Firstname2} onChange={this.props.setFirstname2}/>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={1}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="examplePassword">Mon âge</Label>
                        <Input type="Age" name="Age" id="exampleAge" value={this.props.Age2} onChange={this.props.setAge2} />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="exampleFonction">Ma fonction</Label>
                        <Input type="Fonction" name="Fonction" id="exampleFonction" value={this.props.Role2} onChange={this.props.setRole2} />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>  
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label className="labelForm" for="StatutSocial">Mon statut</Label>
                        <Input type="select" name="StatutSocial" id="StatutSocial" value={this.props.Statut2} onChange={this.props.setStatut2}>
                          <option>Actionnaire</option>
                          <option>Gérant.e ou co Gérant.e</option>
                          <option>Salarié.e</option>
                          <option>Soutien</option>
                        </Input>
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={2}>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <Label for="Finance">Mes attentes financière</Label>
                        <Input type="Finance" name="Attente Financiere" id="Finance" value={this.props.Money2} onChange={this.props.setMoney2}/>    
                      </FormGroup>
                   </Col>
                </Row>
            </Form>
           <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around mt-3" >
              <p className= "Passion">Passion</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Expérience</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Réseau</p>
              <p className= "Passion">Formation</p> 
           </Row>
           <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Passion2} onChange={this.props.setPassion2} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Experience2} onChange={this.props.setExperience2} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Reseau2} onChange={this.props.setReseau2} count={4}  size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} /> 
            <ReactStars value={this.props.Formation2} onChange={this.props.setFormation2} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'} />
           </Row> 
         </CardBody> 
        </Card> 
       </Card>
       <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
        <a href="ajout" className="round-button">+</a>
       </Row>
    </div>   
     );
    }   
   }

const mapActionToProps = {
  //CARD NUMBER ONE//
  setFirstname : setFirstname,
  setAge: setAge,
  setRole: setRole,
  setStatut: setStatut,
  setMoney: setMoney,
  setPassion: setPassion,
  setExperience: setExperience,
  setReseau: setReseau,
  setFormation: setFormation,
   //CARD NUMBER TWO//
  setFirstname1 : setFirstname1,
  setAge1: setAge1,
  setRole1: setRole1,
  setStatut1: setStatut1,
  setMoney1: setMoney1,
  setPassion1: setPassion1,
  setExperience1: setExperience1,
  setReseau1: setReseau1,
  setFormation1: setFormation1,
   //CARD NUMBER THREE//
  setFirstname2 : setFirstname2,
  setAge2: setAge2,
  setRole2: setRole2,
  setStatut2: setStatut2,
  setMoney2: setMoney2,
  setPassion2: setPassion2,
  setExperience2: setExperience2,
  setReseau2: setReseau2,
  setFormation2: setFormation2,
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   //CARD NUMBER ONE//
  team: state.team,
  Firstname : state.team.Firstname,
  Age : state.team.Age,
  Role: state.team.Role,
  Statut: state.team.Statut,
  Money: state.team.Money,
  Passion: state.team.Passion,
  Experience: state.team.Experience,
  Reseau: state.team.Reseau,
  Formation: state.team.Formation,
   //CARD NUMBER TWO//
  Firstname1 : state.team.Firstname1,
  Age1 : state.team.Age1,
  Role1: state.team.Role1,
  Statut1: state.team.Statut1,
  Money1: state.team.Money1,
  Passion1: state.team.Passion1,
  Experience1: state.team.Experience1,
  Reseau1: state.team.Reseau1,
  Formation1: state.team.Formation1,
   //CARD NUMBER THREE//
  Firstname2 : state.team.Firstname2,
  Age2 : state.team.Age2,
  Role2: state.team.Role2,
  Statut2: state.team.Statut2,
  Money2: state.team.Money2,
  Passion2: state.team.Passion2,
  Experience2: state.team.Experience2,
  Reseau2: state.team.Reseau2,
  Formation2: state.team.Formation2
 }
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(TeamEditor);
```

I do not know what to put in my constructor, neither on my button (link).

Comment: One simple card has to be a separate component. In your props has to be prop `team` not `Team` object keys are case sensitive. And you should `this.props.team.map(card=><YourCard...)` so render method will react on any changes in props received from redux. I also  recomend this free video course https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist

Comment: About posting here react code by itself - I recomend this online sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new it's free and you can even install npm es6 dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) where should I put the "this.props.team.map"? in the render before the return? And do you mean that i should have one component per card?

Comment: You should put it whereever you need this cards to clone one after an other, but generally in render method.

Comment: Whatever is repeated should be either  separate component or at least separate method, so put what will clone (card with it's contents) to separate method/component and import it to this component containing cards. This is good example of same usage, but treat Todo as your Card with it's contents: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos

Comment: Looking longer at your code `this.props.team.map` should be instead of `for (let i= 0; i<=this.Team +1 ; i++){` after return. And forget about "separate component" but simply put repeated components inside one div - beacuse react component needs one parent element.

Comment: Should I write it this way: this.props.team.map() = {  and then return()? and copy and paste three times the card code?

Comment: I will post soon whole answer. `this.props.team.map() =` is incorrect.

Comment: What about your reducers? It seems you copy state to global state, what seems incorrect. I need to rethink my answer, before posting it here. Also forget, props are not for methods - I was thinking about asctions.

Comment: This is the beginning of what's in my reducer: const teamReducer = (state = {}, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type){
    case SET_FIRST_NAME:
      let Firstname = {...state, Firstname: payload.Firstname}
      return Firstname;
    case SET_AGE:
      let Age = {...state, Age: payload.Age}
      return Age; and so on...

Comment: and this is what's in Action: export const SET_AGE = 'team:setAge';
  
export const setAge = (e) => {
  return {
    type: SET_AGE,
    payload: {
      Age: e.target.value
    }
  }
} and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Answering all your questions. You don't need constructor unless you make some computations on parent class or on received props before class creation. Look carefuly at your code - you don't see yet difference between `props` received from global state and local `state`, but to make minimal changes I will only explain the difference - **local component state** is **when there is no need to share it with other components**, so storing this in state, than copy to store, than send it to props is not right. Rather use initial state in reducer and in connect method skip first argument `connect(undefined, ...`.

Look also at `mapDispatchToProps` method - this should be function, not an object, unless newest redux allows it, it's function because you may need some computations before passing it to global state (store), same idea for mapStateToProps.

```
class TeamEditor extends Component {

    /* no need for state (state is not the same as props) and without constructor
you can write state = {here your local state}; no need for 'this' keyword
*/
    state = {
        Team: [],
        //...other initial parameters
    };
    //better use arrow function - no need to use .bind in constructor
    render = () => {
        return (<div className="mr-2">
                {this.props.team.map(t => (<Card className="Editor-card">
                            <Row>
                                <Col md={4}>
                                    <CardHeader className="card-header-warning card-header-icon">
                                        <div className="card-icon card-icon-team">
                                            <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '../assets/images/001-trade.svg'} width="40px" className="icon"
                                                 alt="icon"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3 className="float-left card-category mt-2"><span className="text-team">Notre équipe</span></h3>
                                    </CardHeader>
                                </Col>
                                <Col md={8}>
                                    <NavLink to="/" className="d-flex justify-content-end mt-0">
                                        <Button className="mt-3">Enregistrer et quitter</Button>
                                    </NavLink>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <Form>
                                        <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
                                            <Col md={2}>
                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="examplePrenom">Mon Prénom</Label>
                                                    <Input type="Prenom" name="Prenom" id="examplePrenom" value={t.Firstname}
                                                           onChange={this.props.setFirstname}/>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col md={1}>
                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="examplePassword">Mon âge</Label>
                                                    <Input type="Age" name="Age" id="exampleAge" value={t.Age} onChange={this.props.setAge}/>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col md={2}>
                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="exampleFonction">Ma fonction</Label>
                                                    <Input type="Fonction" name="Fonction" id="exampleFonction" value={t.Role}
                                                           onChange={this.props.setRole}/>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col md={2}>
                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label className="labelForm" for="StatutSocial">Mon statut</Label>
                                                    <Input type="select" name="StatutSocial" id="StatutSocial" value={t.Statut}
                                                           onChange={t.setStatut}>
                                                        <option>Actionnaire</option>
                                                        <option>Gérant.e ou co Gérant.e</option>
                                                        <option>Salarié.e</option>
                                                        <option>Soutien</option>
                                                    </Input>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col md={2}>
                                                <FormGroup>
                                                    <Label for="Finance">Mes attentes financière</Label>
                                                    <Input type="Finance" name="Attente Financiere" id="Finance" value={t.Money}
                                                           onChange={t.setMoney}/>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                    </Form>
                                    <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around mt-3">
                                        <p className="Passion">Passion</p>
                                        <p className="Passion">Expérience</p>
                                        <p className="Passion">Réseau</p>
                                        <p className="Passion">Formation</p>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">
                                        <ReactStars value={t.Passion} onChange={this.props.setPassion} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'}/>
                                        <ReactStars value={t.Experience} onChange={this.props.setExperience} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'}/>
                                        <ReactStars value={t.Reseau} onChange={this.props.setReseau} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'}/>
                                        <ReactStars value={t.Formation} onChange={this.props.setFormation} count={4} size={20} color2={'#ffd700'}/>
                                    </Row>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Card>
                    )
                )}
                <Row className="d-flex justify-content-around">

                    <a href="ajout" className="round-button" onClick={
                        // no idea what method should be here but Team seems o be an object not method
                    }>+</a>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );


    };
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    setFirstname: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setFirstname(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setAge: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setAge(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setRole: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setRole(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setStatut: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setStatut(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setMoney: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setMoney(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setPassion: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setPassion(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setExperience: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setExperience(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setReseau: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setReseau(/* parameters for this action */)),
    setFormation: (/* parameters for this action */) => dispatch(setFormation(/* parameters for this action */)),
});
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    Team: state.team,
    Firstname: state.team.Firstname,
    Age: state.team.Age,
    Role: state.team.Role,
    Statut: state.team.Statut,
    Money: state.team.Money,
    Passion: state.team.Passion,
    Experience: state.team.Experience,
    Reseau: state.team.Reseau,
    Formation: state.team.Formation
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TeamEditor);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just now found and fixed one syntax mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for your time! I've tried that code but my browser says ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined . I guess that I may have missed something somewhere?

Comment: And the thing is that I will need that functionality on an other component which is why I need to use redux

Comment: If you get this error, this means `this.props.team` is not an array and also not defined in this case. To clarify some things - I'm not saying using redux is wrong (just the oposite), I say, you can organize data in a way, you skip state in `TeamEditor` and keep it only in store and props.